# Is there any function to calculate condition number of sparse matrix in Eigen libraray?

Tags: linear-solver, iterative-method, condition-number, eigen

The function JacobiSVD and BDCSVD can calcuate condtion number of a dense matrix via singular values.
However I need to know condition number of a sparese matrix due to slow computation speed using iterative linear solver. I can't find such function. If the sparse matrix is converted to one dense one in advance, the memory allocation occur because of large size of the matrix(about 10,000 x 10, 000). Many people may encounter this problem. Is there one way there to calculate condition number for a large sparese matrix in Eigen?

Comment: I can only find dense condition number estimation: "New in beta2: Add fast reciprocal condition number estimator in dense LU and Cholesky decompositions." http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=3.3

Comment: But see: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/Eigen/src/Core/ConditionEstimator.h

Comment: calculating != estimating. Would a (non-guaranteed) estimate be sufficient for you OP?

Comment: ^this. Computing eigenvalues/condition numbers is expensive for sparse matrices. But there are randomized algorithms that are much cheaper.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I agree with you. Usually it is hard to calculate condition number exactly. An approximate condition number is helpful to evaluate the problem.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Is there any function which implements randomized algortithms in Eigen? Any material on such techniques will be expected.

Comment: 10000 by 10000 isn't large- it requires less than a gigabyte of RAM to store such a matrix in double precision.  If you just want to investigate the conditioning of some sample matrices, there's absolutely no reason not to convert to full and compute the condition number approximately using an LU factorization or more precisely using the SVD.  Once you have a better understanding of the ill-conditioning of your problems, you can look to improve the preconditioner that you're using with your iterative method.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thanks. The size of the matrix is about 10000x10000. Sorry. In fact the exact size is 16000x16000. About 2 gigabytes of RAM is required to store it. 8G memory is available on my computer. Memory allocation fails when the sparse matrix is converted to dense  one. If I resize the matrix from 16000 x 16000 to 8000 x 8000 like image downsampling by suming up neighboring 2x2 elements, whata will happed to the condition number?

Comment: SuiteSparse has a routine called `cholmod rcond` which estimates the reciprocal condition number of a sparse matrix that can be decomposed with an LLT or LDLT factorization. "Returns a rough estimate of the reciprocal of the condition number: the minimum entry on the diagonal of L (or absolute entry of D for an LDLT factorization) divided by the maximum entry." This seems like a viable alternative to forming the dense matrix.

https://fossies.org/linux/SuiteSparse/CHOLMOD/Doc/CHOLMOD_UserGuide.pdf

Comment: @CharlieS Why is reciprocal condition number is estimated instead of condition number?

Comment: @JoggingSong Presumably, it is to prevent a divide by zero (or near zero) if your matrix is ill-conditioned.